# Connecting to AD using JNDI - Why must the security principal be supplied in the format username@domain?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to connect to an Active Directory using the standard Java (javax.naming.*) libraries.

This seems to work exactly like connecting to any other LDAP except for one difference: The `SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` needs to be supplied in the form

```
sAMAccountName@domainComponent(s)
```

e.g.

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "foo@bar.baz.org"
```

Trying to use use a valid DN which points to the exact same user like

```
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=foo,cn=Users,dc=bar,dc=baz,dc=org
```

result in a `AuthenticationException`. Is this something specific to Active Directory? For other LDAP DS, the last approach always worked.

Comment: Please paste the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

This is not AD authentication what you are performing. You are performing a mere LDAP bind. AD auth is Kerberos.

The LDAP compement of the AD expects principal either as UPN, samaccountname or NT4-style logins. No DNs accepted.